MikroTik VLAN AccessPort doesn't work

I have a problem with configuring access port on my MikroTik CRS312-4C+8XG-RM. Below, I show you my config. 
I expect that on combo4 I can connect my computer to my VLAN10. In general my network works fine. MikroTik is another switch which I want to add to my network. 
I bought MikroTik first time and I need help. I don't know how can I achieve my purpose. In this time, I can connect to admin panel MikroTik from my computer who is connected to my other switch in VLAN10.
Other informations:
my DHCP - WS2022
my Router - FortiGate
My current MikroTik configuration:









